# recursive function in collection

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I am using c# and List collection and loaded the values. Once it is done I am trying to read them recursively but some how I am not able to achieve this.

the following is my main code.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var node = new Node
                    {
                        Name = "N1",
                        Nodes =
                            new List<Node>
                                {
                                    new Node { Name = "N1a" },
                                    new Node { Name = "N1b", Nodes = new List<Node> { new Node { Name = "N1B1" } } },
                                    new Node
                                        {
                                            Name = "N1c",
                                            Nodes =
                                                new List<Node> { new Node { Name = "N1C1", Nodes = new List<Node> {new Node{Name = "N1C1A"} } } }
                                        }
                                }
                    };
                GetNodes( node );
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

 public class Node
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public IList<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        }
```

and the function call is following

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(Node node)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

            foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
            {
                return GetNodes(n);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Could any one please help me to fix the recursive function?

Comment: OK your function will cease on the first node.. so, what are you actually trying to do, get nodes, will not amass nodes and then return *all* them in one hit..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to print the names of all the nodes,

```
public static void GetNodes(Node node)
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        GetNodes(n);
    }
}
```

If you want to flatten the tree,

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(Node node)
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    yield return node;
    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        foreach(var innerN in GetNodes(n))
        {
            yield return innerN;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd always add the health warning that if you store the result of a method that uses yield you can only every iterate over the collection once.

Comment: How do you mean? If you call `var iterator = GetNodes(myNode);`, you can iterate over it as many times as you want without a problem.

Comment: Hmmmm... just tried and and you're right. I'm sure this has bitten me before but must have been some other problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Rawling thanks for your the answer it is working perfectly * only the first part or I don't know. Flatten the tree is not working for me. Could you please tell how to get that?

Comment: If you actually want console output from the second one, you need something like `foreach(var n in GetNodes(node)) Console.WriteLine(n.Name);`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes(Node node)
{
    if (node == null) return null;

    var nodes = new List<Node>();
    nodes.Add(node);

    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

    if (node.Nodes != null)
    {
        foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
        {
            nodes.AddRange(GetNodes(n));
        }
    }

    return nodes;
}}
```

Comment: Hi @Cuong, thanks for your the answer it is working perfectly. Though I was selecting the first answer due to less amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your method only every returns null, or calls itself and then either returns null, or calls itself..... so at the end of the day it returns null or doesn't terminate. If you want to seralize the values you can write them into a list at the same point in the code as you write them to the console.

```
public static void GetNodes(Node node, List<Node> output)
{
    if (node == null)
        return;

    output.Add(node);
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);

    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        GetNodes(n, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @James, thanks for your the answer it is working perfectly. Though I was selecting the first answer due to less amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

You return from your method inside a loop immediately, on teh first iteration. No other iterations is performed.